# MongoDB unique count

Tags: mongodb

Hi I will try to give a simple example of what I am trying to achieve, I've tried using the aggregation pipeline and distinct but I am a bit lost

I have the following records

```
item1 - A : "xxxx", U : "1111"
item2 - A : "xxxx", U : "2222"
item3 - A : "bbbb", U : "1111"
item4 - A : "bbbb", U : "3333"
item4 - A : "xxxx", U : "3333"
```

I am trying to write a query which will give me a unique count of U where U has a record which `match A = "xxxx" and A = "bbbb"`

so the above case the count would be 2 as there is only two users who has a record for `bbbb and xxxx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using aggregation?
Original data:

```
> db.items.find({}, {_id: 0})
{ "A" : "xxxx", "U" : "1111" }
{ "A" : "xxxx", "U" : "2222" }
{ "A" : "bbbb", "U" : "1111" }
{ "A" : "bbbb", "U" : "3333" }
{ "A" : "xxxx", "U" : "3333" }
```

Aggregation query:

```
> db.items.aggregate([{$group: {_id: '$U', alist: {$push: '$A'}}}, {$match: {alist: {$all: ['bbbb', 'xxxx']}}}])
{ "_id" : "3333", "alist" : [ "bbbb", "xxxx" ] }
{ "_id" : "1111", "alist" : [ "xxxx", "bbbb" ] }
```

Comment: i think this works, can i complicate things slightly add add a status to the record so exactly the same but an extra condition the status lets call it S must = 1 for example

Comment: It depends where you need to add it. If it is filtering after aggregation, than just add this to $match: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/ If not, please elaborate and give an example.

Comment: {"S": "1", "A" : "xxxx", "U" : "1111" }

{"S": "1", "A" : "xxxx", "U" : "2222" }

{"S": "1", "A" : "bbbb", "U" : "1111" }

{"S": "2", "A" : "bbbb", "U" : "3333" }

{"S": "2", "A" : "xxxx", "U" : "3333" }

So the user needs to have a record which matches A = xxxx and S = 2 and a record which match  A = bbbb and S = 2

Comment: Same as for A, push S values to `slist` and then use $all for `slist` in $match.

Comment: Sorry could you give me an example pls similar to the above that was perfect

Comment: db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate([
{$group: {_id: '$U', 
    alist: {$push: '$A', $push: "S" }}}, 
    {$match: {
        alist: {
            $all: [ObjectId("553f4c6eb015aa0b44cc26b8"), ObjectId("55827c5ab015a00e4420a1ea")]}}}])

So im pushing A and S but how do i test if s is equal to 1

Comment: Just to make it clear, what is the expected result for the new data set in comment?

Comment: I would expect count of 1 now that i have added a S which must equal 2

Comment: If you need this for initial filtering, then you can use: `db.items.aggregate([{$match: {S: "1"}}, {$group: {_id: '$U', alist: {$push: '$A'}}}, {$match: {alist: {$all: ['bbbb', 'xxxx']}}}])`